# WP check specific class added to html tag

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress is there any way to check if any specific class added to html tag of document? More Likely **Modernzir** (browser based) classes for enqueuing scripts etc.

```
<html class="queryselector svg cssall willchange audio canvas video adownload bgpositionshorthand cssremunit rgba csscalc cssgradients csschunit supports no-touchevents **no-cssscrollbar** cssvhunit cssvwunit formvalidation cssanimations appearance no-backdropfilter backgroundcliptext csscolumns csscolumns-width no-csscolumns-span csscolumns-fill csscolumns-gap csscolumns-rule csscolumns-rulecolor csscolumns-rulestyle csscolumns-rulewidth no-csscolumns-breakbefore no-csscolumns-breakafter no-csscolumns-breakinside no-cssgridlegacy cssgrid cssfilters flexbox shapes csstransforms backgroundblendmode fa-events-icons-ready wf-opensans-n4-active wf-active" lang="en-US">
```

For example if you check above code block, you can see that modernizr has added multiple classes based on browser compatibility. So i simply want to check if **<html>** has any specific class, for instance **no-cssscrollbar** to check if browser supports CSS3 scroll bar.

I tried different approaches including php `class_exists()` function, but no luck so far. I want to detect class without JS or jQuery approach.

Comment: PHP class_exists is for Classes in PHP, not for HTML class names. If the classes are added via Javascript, you cannot obtain the class names using PHP. Your only option is with Javascript. In fact it is also your best option. PHP cares very little about your front-end code.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, sure i do can check class with js but thought there might be some way to get around with PHP or Wordpress. Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't have a whole lot to do with Wordpress, though.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Can you give an example of how this would be used?

Comment: Sure let me explain. I want to enqueue specific css if browser doesn't support any CSS3 feature, e.g **Scroll Bar**. Further if somehow we can manage to get all classes in array than we can filter any specific class to enqueue custom styles & scripts.
<br>
Something similar to **get_body_class()**.
<br>
`$body_classes = get_body_class();
if ( in_array( 'some-class', $body_classes ) ) {
    //Single product page
}`